# Checking first time app launch using Cordova 3.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3

Is there a way in Cordova 3.0 to check if that's the first time the application runs without using the DB for that purpose.

Comment: you could use a localStorage variable

Comment: write an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use localStorage to check for a variable. Try something like this:

in docummentready event:

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem('has_run') == '') {
    //do some stuff if has not loaded before
    window.localStorage.setItem('has_run', 'true');
}
```

Comment: What about the **data expiration** from user agent?

Answer (score 1):

Dawson Loudon's solution didn't work for me but try this:

```
var count = window.localStorage.getItem('hasRun');

if(count){
   console.log("second time app launch");
}else{
  // set variable in localstore
  window.localStorage.setItem('hasRun',1);
  console.log("first time app launch");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must use sessionStorage instead of localStorage.

The correct code will be:

```
var count = window.sessionStorage.getItem('hasRun');

if (count) {
  console.log("second time app launch");
} else {
  // set variable in localstore
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('hasRun', 1);
  console.log("first time app launch");
}
```

It's because localStorage is persistent while sessionStorage ain't..

Comment: That's why you want to use localStorage, it has to be persistent otherwise the data could be removed, and it looks like your app is launching for the first time.